# Qt chamando o metodo em outra class

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

Estou chamando um método de outra classe após a inserção de dados. 
Mas esta retornando um erro do SQLite:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
```

Código:

exemplo_insert.cpp

```
void DialogVenda::inserte_venda(){
     //QSqlQuery etc....
     if (qry.lastInsertId()>0){
            QMessageBox::information(this,"Cadastro de pedido", "Pedido cadastrado com sucesso.");
            MainPrincipal *pt= new MainPrincipal(this);
            pt->tableView_listaVendas();
     }
}
```

MainPrincipal.cpp

```
 MainPrincipal::MainPrincipal(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainPrincipal){

    ui->setupUi(this);
    base = new connection(NAME_BASE);
    if(!base->openBD()){
       QMessageBox::critical(this, "Erro", ERRO_BASE);
       return;
     }
 }   


void MainPrincipal::tableView_listaVendas(){
 model = new QSqlQueryModel;
    model->setQuery("SELEC * FROM empresa_estoqueSaida WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', saida_dataCadastro)='"+dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"'");
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Cliente"));
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Endereço"));
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Valor"));
    model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Pagamento"));
    model->setHeaderData(6, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Data"));
    ui->tableView_vendas->setModel(model);
}
```

O objetivo é atualizar o `tableView_vendas` após a inserção da venda.

Comment: Você está abrindo mais de uma instância da conexão com o banco de dados na sua aplicação?

Comment: Tenho no MainPrincipal construtor `base_dados = new Conexao(NOME_BASE_DADOS);`

Comment: A conexão esta uma única vez no `MainPrincipal::MainPrincipal(){base_dados = new Conexao(NOME_BASE_DADOS);}` . Achou eu o problema esta aqui abrindo `new MainPrincipal` ele esta rodando toda classe de novo.

Comment: Então é isto. Esta conexão precisa ser aberta e existir uma única vez na aplicação, certo?

Comment: Sim. Olha ae em cima o código, adicionei o construtor que tem a ligação da base de dados.

Comment: Tenta usar thread lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não tenho certeza *absoluta* de que esse é o problema, pois você não colocou o(s) trecho(s) de código que executam o método `inserte_venda`. De todas as formas, o problema parece estar justamente ai.

O método `void DialogVenda::inserte_venda()` contém código para criar uma nova instância da janela do tipo `MainPrincipal`, herdada de `QMainWindow`, toda vez que é chamado (o que ele faz executando a linha `MainPrincipal *pt= new MainPrincipal(this);`). Não há necessariamente nada de errado nisso, mas atente para o fato de que o construtor dessa classe de janela principal cria a conexão com o banco de dados e a abre, [como vc mesmo percebe em seus comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83023/qt-chamando-o-metodo-em-outra-class#comment168431_83023). Logo, a conexão é criada e aberta *a cada chamada* de `inserte_venda`, indiretamente pelo construtor de `MainPrincipal`.

O seu código não contém um destrutor para a classe `MainPrincipal`, então a conexão criada e aberta não está sendo fechada. De todas as formas, provavelmente você também tem ai um potencial vazamento de memória, no sentido de que toda instância de `MainPrincipal` criada a cada chamada de `inserte_venda` está sendo amarrada à instância de `DialogVenda` (por causa do `this` que vc passa no construtor de `MainPrincipal`). Se `DialogVenda` não sair do escopo, as instância criada para `MainPrincipal` também não vai sair automaticamente (a deleção automática do Qt funciona dessa forma, dependendo do objeto pai ser deletado). Então, mesmo que você tivesse um destrutor, talvez não funcionasse como esperado.

Uma solução seria você não instanciar a classe `MainPrincipal` com o operador `New`, mas sim fazer `MainPrincipal pt;` e então `pt.tableView_listaVendas();`. Dessa forma, `pt` vai ser instanciado [na pilha (*stack*) ao invés do *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap), e será destruído quando o escopo se encerrar (isto é, quando o método `inserte_venda` terminar).

Mas uma solução melhor seria você separar a conexão de qualquer outra classe, especialmente se essa classe envolve a interface gráfica. Em teoria a sua aplicação deveria verificar a conexão ao iniciar, abri-la e mantê-la aberta durante seu tempo de execução (ou gerenciar isso de forma dinâmica, mas ainda assim separada). Procure construir uma classe de dados que seja amplamente acessível e única. Como, por exemplo, utilizando [o padrão singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton).